# Ionic 3: ios-file-picker crashing app on device running iOS 10.x, not 11

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ios10, icloud, ionic-native

I'm using the plugin [here: iOSFilePicker](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/ios-file-picker/) to access iCloud from my app to grab a file.

It works in debug on my machine, built through ionic command line with:

```
ionic cordova build ios --prod --release
```

However, when I actually archive the build in Xcode and release through the store beta channel for testing, the app crashes when I invoke the `iOSFilePicker` on an iOS 10.x device (iPhone 5).

Has anyone got an idea why?

Things to note:

- working fine on iOS 11.x (iPhone 6 + 6s)
- No errors, just a complete crash back to the home-screen iOS 10.x
- I enabled capabilities for iCloud in Xcode, see screenshot below...
- ...despite the containers checkboxes not being ticked, it works when I         run it on ios 11.x devices.

[image]

For reference, here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "mycompany-web-ionic",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "MyCompany Ltd",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.9",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-chooser": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-picker": "^4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-transfer": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.7.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "^1.0.20",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "angular2-fusioncharts": "^1.0.2-rc.5",
    "highcharts": "^6.1.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "rxjs": "5.5.7",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.1.9",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: Any errors? Or does the app just crash?

Comment: have u enable iCloud inside xcode -> Capabilities

Comment: see edits guys, thanks.

Comment: You can check this blog post for integrating FusionCharts in an Ionic framework - https://www.fusioncharts.com/blog/create-charts-in-ionic-2/

Comment: hey @Dave, did you ever find a solution for this one? I'm experiencing the exact same problem with an iPhone 5c (iOS 10.3.3)

Comment: Nope! Not tried it for ages either.